# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils._joblib'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, joblib

I'm using python 3.6 on on Anaconda Jupyter notebooks platform. My pc uses win 8.1 as OS.

I was trying to import PCA from sklearn using the following lines:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn import decomposition 
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
```

the third line returns a Module error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils._joblib'`

Strangely, I couldn't find any record on this error online! I'd appreciate any help. I copied the complete error message below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-375-2e95ea83a366> in <module>()
      1 import sklearn
----> 2 from sklearn import decomposition
      3 from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
      4 # Make an instance of the Model
      5 pca = PCA(.95)

E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\__init__.py in <module>()
      9 from .incremental_pca import IncrementalPCA
     10 from .kernel_pca import KernelPCA
---> 11 from .sparse_pca import SparsePCA, MiniBatchSparsePCA
     12 from .truncated_svd import TruncatedSVD
     13 from .fastica_ import FastICA, fastica

E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\sparse_pca.py in <module>()
     11 from ..linear_model import ridge_regression
     12 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
---> 13 from .dict_learning import dict_learning, dict_learning_online
     14 
     15 

E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\dict_learning.py in <module>()
     15 
     16 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
---> 17 from ..utils._joblib import Parallel, delayed, effective_n_jobs
     18 from ..externals.six.moves import zip
     19 from ..utils import (check_array, check_random_state, gen_even_slices,

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils._joblib'
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this error on my machine.  Can you run sklearn.show_versions() and post the output here?  Also, only import the classes/objects that you need, don't import the whole library if you don't have to.  If you just need PCA from sklearn, only run "from sklearn.decomposition import PCA".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install and import joblib directly:

```
!pip install joblib
import joblib
```

Answer (score 2):

[This comment on a PR](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/13531/files#r276153496) in May 2019 mentions that they wanted to ditch it.

As of June 2019, [`sklearn.utils._joblib` is no longer a thing](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/13676).

- Why this code didn't work back in March is hard to say, as it was still [supported the **May** release](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#id15)

Analysis: you've got old versions in your environment. Perhaps `pip install -r requirements.txt` got you, overriding the working version, or something else.

Recommendation: make a new `conda` environment, reinstall sklearn and joblib (via `conda install scikit-learn joblib`) in that environment and move forward.

Comment: Many tutorials use from sklearn.utils import _joblib.
Should we use from sklearn.utils import joblib instead?
Or from sklearn.externals import joblib?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem but the description is 'No module named 'sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel'. I installed and uninstalled sklearn and joblib repeatedly and it didn't work. Finally I solved this problem by commenting it in the source package code.

Comment: Providing the commands that you tried and the files that you've modified would be more helpful.