# AttributeError: module "sklearn.utils" has no attribute "_joblib" when inheriting class `sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.`

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I need to extract the probabilities of each model trained in `sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier`. The reason for doing this is to estimate uncertainty around XGBoostClassifier models.

To do this, I create a extended class inheriting from `sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier` and adding a new method allowing to obtain these probabilities. Please note that this problem is different from [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils._joblib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965751/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn-utils-joblib)

I show the piece of code that I have implemented so far, below:

The necessary modules

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.base import _partition_estimators
from sklearn.utils import check_array
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
import sklearn.utils as su
```

The child class inheriting from `BaggingClassifier`

```
class EBaggingClassifier(BaggingClassifier):
    """
    Extends the class BaggingClassifier fromsklearn

    """

    def __init__(self,
                 base_estimator=None,
                 n_estimators=10,
                 max_samples=1.0,
                 max_features=1.0,
                 bootstrap=True,
                 bootstrap_features=False,
                 oob_score=False,
                 warm_start=False,
                 n_jobs=1,
                 random_state=None,
                 verbose=0):

        super().__init__(
                 base_estimator,
                 n_estimators,
                 max_samples,
                 max_features,
                 bootstrap,
                 bootstrap_features,
                 oob_score,
                 warm_start,
                 n_jobs,
                 random_state,
                 verbose)
```

The new method allowing to calculate the probability of each estimator is defined below.

```
    def predict_proball(self, X):
        """
        Computes the probability of each individual estimator

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape = [n_samples, n_features]
            The training input samples. Sparse matrices are accepted only if
            they are supported by the base estimator.

        Returns
        -------
        p : array of shape = [n_samples, n_classes]
            The class probabilities of the input samples. The order of the
            classes corresponds to that in the attribute `classes_`.
        """

        check_is_fitted(self, "classes_")
        # Check data
        X = check_array(
            X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc'], dtype=None,
            force_all_finite=False
        )

        if self.n_features_ != X.shape[1]:
            raise ValueError("Number of features of the model must "
                             "match the input. Model n_features is {0} and "
                             "input n_features is {1}."
                             "".format(self.n_features_, X.shape[1]))

        # Parallel loop
        n_jobs, n_estimators, starts = _partition_estimators(self.n_estimators,
                                                             self.n_jobs)

        all_proba = su._joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
                             **self._parallel_args())(
            su._joblib.delayed(BaggingClassifier._parallel_predict_proba)(
                self.estimators_[starts[i]:starts[i + 1]],
                self.estimators_features_[starts[i]:starts[i + 1]],
                X,
                self.n_classes_)
            for i in range(n_jobs))

        return all_proba
```

I instantiate this class using `XGBoostClassifier` as the base estimator:

```
base_estimator = XGBoostClassifier(**params)
estimator = EBaggingClassifier(base_estimator=base_estimator, max_samples=0.8, n_estimators=10)
```

and then the `estimator` using `estimator.fit(X, y)`, where `X` and `y` are `pandas.DataFrame` objects. When I try to run `estimator.predict_proball(X)` I get

```
>>> estimator.predict_proball(X)
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.utils' has no attribute '_joblib'
```

Does someone know why this is happening? Looking at the `BaggingClassifier` [script](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b7b4d3e2f/sklearn/ensemble/bagging.py#L652) the function 'sklearn.utils._joblib' should be available.

FYI:

```
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.19.2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `scikit-learn` version. Version `'0.19.2'` does not have `_joblib`, you can refer [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/0.19.2/sklearn/utils). or you can just check using the following:

```
dir(su)
```

You need to update `scikit-learn` and the latest version has `_joblib`, you can refer [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn/utils).

You get the following in version `'0.20.2'`:

```
>>> dir(su)
['Bunch', 'DataConversionWarning', 'IS_PYPY', 'Memory', 'Parallel', 'Sequence', 
'_IS_32BIT', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', 
'__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_joblib', 
'_show_versions', 'as_float_array', 'assert_all_finite', 'axis0_safe_slice', 
'check_X_y', 'check_array', 'check_consistent_length', 'check_random_state', 
'check_symmetric', 'class_weight', 'column_or_1d', 'compute_class_weight', 
'compute_sample_weight', 'cpu_count', 'delayed', 'deprecate', 'deprecated', 
'deprecation', 'effective_n_jobs', 'fixes', 'gen_batches', 'gen_even_slices', 
'get_chunk_n_rows', 'get_config', 'hash', 'indexable', 'indices_to_mask', 
'is_scalar_nan', 'issparse', 'msg', 'murmurhash', 'murmurhash3_32', 'np', 
'numbers', 'parallel_backend', 'platform', 'register_parallel_backend', 
'resample', 'safe_indexing', 'safe_mask', 'safe_sqr', 'shuffle', 'struct', 
'tosequence', 'validation', 'warnings']
```

You can update `scikit-learn` as follows:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```