# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.joblib'

Tags: python-3.x, installation, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm using Python 3, and trying to use `joblib`. I have the following I am trying to import:

```
import sklearn.externals as extjoblib
import joblib
```

I receive the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.joblib'`

I try to use  `pip3 install sklearn.external --user`  but have had no luck. Could someone help me install this?

Comment: Hi, I think that module has been deprecated [see this](https://github.com/skekre98/NBA-Search/issues/19)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils.\_joblib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965751/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn-utils-joblib)

Answer (score 20):

I got the same `ModuleNotFoundError` but in another context, while trying to import a library, and found this workaround useful:

```
import joblib

sys.modules['sklearn.externals.joblib'] = joblib
```

The reason being that `sklearn.externals` does not have a `joblib` module, at least in my version, so I normally import the `joblib` package and then tell `sklearn.externals` where to find by using `sys.modules`.

Once I did that, I found that the error disappeared when I imported the library again.

Answer (score 4):

since scikit-learn version 0.23, the package joblib is deprecated from sklearn, you can just import joblib individually.

```
import joblib
```

That's it.

Comment: That is basically they same answer as the one from CharlieNeutron

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote

```
import joblib
```

instead of both

```
import sklearn.external.joblib as joblib
import joblib
```

This worked for me.